# Laravel factories being consumed by table seeders and tests. Best practices/How to do it

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.6, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to write some Laravel `factories` so that we can seed all tables upfront and also use them for tests.

*I'm not very experienced with testing and I have some doubts on which premises should factories be built.*

Let's use this simple example, 2 tables:

- users
- notes

Notes have a `user_id` field with a `FK`.

Should I make the `notes` factory to be able to create `users` (calling `users` factory) or expect that in any test that I try to create `notes` I 
 have already created `users` that can be associated with the `notes`?

Please give some practical example if you may.

Comment: Could you have your Note Factory pull a random user from the database and assign a `user_id` based on that?

Comment: I've found it useful to include automatic creation of related models within the factory definition. Simply because it often saves you from writing additional code. And when you need to attach it to a specific model you can do that on the go: `factory(Model::class)->create(['related_id' => $related->id])`. As for tests, I think it's best to create the data within the test, otherwise you can quickly lose track of what data you already have and should expect. As for this question, it's primarily opinion based and not the best fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimLewis yes I can. That was my solution for now to do it as you say. Wondering if it is a good practice or a limited one.

Comment: Hard to say really; my usage of Factories is pretty limited, but I feel like *creating* Users in a Note Factory is somewhat backwards. Pulling them from the database, choosing one at random and attaching a Note to it sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship while seeding can be done. Try this code in your NoteFactory.

```
'user_id' => function(){
      return App\User::all()->random();
}
```

Note that your UserFactory should run first and then NoteFactory.